# How can ensure a form contains the values from the previous request?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form which is not based on a entity class. It is a filter form, so whenever a user selects/enters a value and then hits 'go', I want the user's values to pre populate the form when the page is refreshed.

I'm using Symfony.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

To example, store values in session and pass data to form. On reset form - clear session.